# Viewing CSS property value suggestions in Notepad++

Tags: css, editor, notepad++

Using Notepad++ 5.7

I was modifying a .css file, when I blocked/selected a rule and accidentally pressed a key in combination with alt or ctrl and other keys in the lower left-hand side of the keyboard...not sure which keys.

Moving on, a list of CSS values came up such as :first-letter a few hundred more. **What key commands are needed to achieve this again and where is the documentation for this feature?** I find it fascinating.

*Code I selected at the time:*

```
input[type=reset]:hover, input[type=submit]:hover{
color:#ffffff;
background-color:#1c1c1c;
cursor:pointer;
border:2px groove #0e0e0e;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

CTRL+Space does that.
As for documentation, try these two:

https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts - shows that CTRL-Space is the shortcut. And if you search for the Auto Completion page there it will describe the file format.